# "Schnapp' sie Dir alle!"--why the apostrophe?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, slang

Why is there an apostrophe after the word *schnapp* in this Pokemon slogan?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The apostrophe signifies that a letter was left out:

> Schnapp**e** sie alle.

This is no longer necessary, or actually correct. [Duden has more](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/bildung-des-imperativs) on the subject.

Comment: Is the vowel in "schnappe" like the additional "e" vowel in "Atme gleichmäßig!"?

Comment: No, in "atme" you do need the "e" cause "atm" is not really pronouncable.

Comment: In some cases (mainly if your word ends in -m or -n) you must not leave out the -e. Atmen (Atme!) is one of them. If your word ends in -d or -t you can leave out the -e in colloquial speech only (Red nicht so laut! Arbeit nicht so viel!), but must use it in formal language. In most other cases the -e can be left out. No apostrophe should be used in any case.